# RAM [Computer software]

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have 2 RAM slots in my motherboard. In Slot#1 I have a 2 GB DDR3 800Mhz RAM. I am planning to add 2 GB RAM more to Slot#2 of my computer. But online stores only has 1333Mhz RAM to buy. So my questions is that Can I use a 800Mhz RAM with a 1333Mhz RAM.

Regards,

A Computer Enthusiast

Comment: Can you provide your motherboard model?

Comment: You're probably confusing actual clock speeds with effective transfer rates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but the faster RAM will run at the slower RAM's speed, unless you have the XMP option in your laptop BIOS.